# Call a method from an another class in Ruby (API rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

The question can be stupid, but I always develop in C# and now I need to develop in Ruby.
And I don't really understand how to call a method from an another class.
I mean, I've this structure :

```
- model
   |_________ my_model.rb
   |_________ helper
                |____ my_helper_class
```

**my_model.rb**

```
   def self.create_new_ticket(member_to_update)
    # I want to call here my_helper_class
    MyHelperClass.generate_guid
   end
```

**my_helper_class :**

```
class MyHelperClass
 
def generate_guid
  return "So haaard"
end

end
```

And I don't have access to my method named ***generate_guid*** from my other class.
I've this type of error :

> uninitialized constant

I would like to have an access with a static class or whatever. The initilize method doesn't work too (given argument problem ??)

So I think I understand bad something with Ruby and the manipulation of objects because of my habits in C#.

Can you help me please ? With some good documentations or an example here ?

Thanks a lot guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your error is straightforward. Your `generate_guid` is not a "static method" or "class method". You have to put `self` in front of it in the definition which will make it a class method.

Another important thing to notice is you have created `/helper` folder inside `/model` so you have to implement helper class inside a module named `Helper` which should be same as folder name.

Helper class should be

```
module Helper
  class MyHelperClass
     def self.generate_guid
      return "So haaard"
    end
  end
end
```

An alternate way to define class methods would be:

```
module Helper
  class MyHelperClass
    class << self 
      def generate_guid
        "So haaard"
      end
     
      def some_other_class_method
         "some thing"
      end  
    end 
  end 
end
```

So, whenever you have to call static method you have to call it with full scope like `Helper::MyHelperClass.generate_guid`

Comment: Ohhhhh great !! I understand better how it works !! So cool ! Who says the Ruby is easiest than the C# ! ahah. Thanks a lot man !